# Given a list of ints, return True if the array contains a 3 next to a 3 somewhere

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to creates a function that returns True if a list contains two consecutive 3 and false if not.
when using this code it doesn't work:

```
def has_33(x):
    for i in range(len(x)-1):
        if x[i:i+2] == [3,3]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

But with this it works:

```
def has_33(x):
    for i in range(len(x)-1):
        if x[i:i+2] == [3,3]:
            return True
    return False
```

For me it's the same thing can you explain to me why plz

Comment: in the first case you always return when i == 0. Just try to run this step by step either with pen and paper or using a debugger, it will be obvious

Comment: try to think of a `return` as in implicit `break` and it becomes obvious why the first version is not working.

Answer (score 3):

In the top code you only check the first 2 indices. In the bottom code you're checking the whole array. Here's why:

In the top code you have an `else` condition, which means that on the first iteration either the `if-condition` is true (i.e. the first and the second element of the list are 3) or you will go into the `else` condition. In either case, you're hitting a `return` statement after checking just the first 2 elements.

In the bottom code, you only `return` if you find something, or once you've finished the whole loop

I've added some print statements to both your functions. You can run this code and see the output to help you understand what's happening:

```
def has_33_incorrect(x):
  print("\nRunning the incorrect function")
  for i in range(len(x)-1):
    print("Checking indices {} and {}".format(i, i+1))
    if x[i:i+2] == [3,3]:
      print("indices contain 2 consecutive 3's. Returning true")
      return True
    else:
      print("indices don't contain 2 consecutive 3's. Returning false")
      return False

def has_33_correct(x):
  print("\nRunning the correct function")
  for i in range(len(x)-1):
    print("Checking indices {} and {}".format(i, i+1))
    if x[i:i+2] == [3,3]:
      print("indices contain 2 consecutive 3's. Returning true")
      return True
  print("Did not find consecutive 3's. Returning false")
  return False


list = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3, 3, 2, 5]
has_33_incorrect(list)
has_33_correct(list)
```

Comment: No worries! Please see FAQ on how to approve answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

One more solution with `any` python builtin:

```
def has_33(l):
     return any(l[i+1] == l[i] == 3 for i in range(len(l) - 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works since if the if condition is false it doesn't return anything, yet in the first function you showed it returns false and exits the function. You shouldn't return anything until you find that its true somewhere, only after you've iterate over the entire list then and only then should you return `False`

```
def has_33(x):
    for i in range(len(x)-1):
        if x[i:i+2] == [3,3]:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the list directly.

```
def has_33(x):
    current = None
    for item in x:
        if current == item == 3:
            return True
        current = item
    return False
```

If you ever find both `current` and `item` are equal to 3, you can return `True` immediately. Otherwise, you will return `False` when the loop exits naturally.

Comment: Note that this function does not constantly create new, two-item lists via slicing.

Answer (score 0):

If you loop through adjacent entries at the same time, you can compare:

```
def adjacent_threes(x):
    for a, b, in zip(x[:-1], x[1:]):
        if a == b == 3:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,it's simple:

```
def has_33(nums):
    for i,num in enumerate(nums):
        if nums[i]==3 and nums[i+1]==3:
                   return True
    return False
```

Answer (score -2):

python code as follows :

```
def has_33(nums):
    my_list = []
    y =len(nums)-1
    for x in range(0,y) :
        if nums[x] == 3 and nums[x+1] == 3:
            my_list.append(1)
        else :
            my_list.append(0)
    print(my_list)
    if 1 in my_list:
        return True
    else :
        return False
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include an explanation of *how* this code block answers the question. This helps to provide context and makes your answer much more useful to those who might come across the same issue later on.